# How to update to Windows 10 build 18917?

Tags: windows, windows-update

I would like to get WSL2 so I enabled Windows Insider Slow and I keep updating my computer again and again but I am stuck to 10.0.18363.

Each time I search for update I get `Feature update to Windows 10, version 2004` it downloads for update, it reboots, then same...

Why is my build not changing and how to update to 18917?

What I see is this:

[image]

Comment: You will have to supply the logs that indicate the reason the feature update failed, in order for us to explain, the reason the feature update failed.  You might try downloading the current ISO and using that instead.  If you are currently running 1903 and are trying to upgrade to 2004, it is not actually clear what build your system is currently on, and that makes a huge difference

Comment: How can I get the logs?

Comment: [This](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/setupdiag) tool might help.  Without more information about your current installation I cannot provide better guidance.  Any information should be in the question body not a comment.